Why won't this onClick jQuery call trigger an action?
I have a link like this:
<a id="create_quiz" href="#">Create Quiz</a>                                                                           

In the HEAD of the HTML page, I have put this:
<script src="https://api.gruntled.com/jquery.js">

  $(document).ready(function(){
  $( "#create_quiz" ).click(function(e) {
      alert("hi");
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("hi")
      $(".editing form").css("display", "none");
      return false;
    } );
});
</script>

But when I load the page in Safari and I click on the link, all that happens is the browser goes to the URL which is #.
I cannot get anything to trigger. The alert never appears.
I did run a search on the page to be sure there was no duplicate use of the ID. But "create_quiz" only appears twice, once in the ID and once in the jQuery code.
I've also (repeatedly) checked the URL from which I'm importing the jQuery.
What do I need to do to make something happens when people click that link?
I was expecting to at least see the alert() that I called.

You need two <script> tags, one for loading jquery.js, another for your script.
